# Solr: boosting by date not returning in right order, is something wrong with my boost?

Tags: sorting, date, solr

I'm using Solr to search for events, and I need events to be boosted by date so that the closer and event is to the current date, the higher its score will be compared to an event with say the same name but a later date. So, "Alumni Reunion" in January 2015 should show up higher on the list of results than "Alumni Reunion" in October 2015.

I read the Solr Relevancy FAQ, and this is the query I'm using in solr:

```
?q={!boost%20b=recip(abs(ms(NOW,dt_startdate)),3.16e-11,1,1)}searchterms&sort=score desc
```

It definitely changes the order of the results, but the order is wrong. For example, one of my searches that gives me back four results is returning them as 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015 when it should be the opposite (April 2015 vs. April 2014, 2015 should show up first). I tried simply changing it to

```
sort=score asc
```

but rather than returning in the opposite order as I'd expect, the order was totally different; it went 2014, 2015, 2012, 2013

What is wrong with my boost? I believe that without the boost, the relevancy should be the same for all of them, because the field that contains the terms I'm searching for is exactly the same for each. The order was actually **better** before I put the boost in; while it wasn't correct, it went 2014, 2015, 2013, 2012 which was closer than it is now.

EDIT: I realize that the boost won't necessarily put it in date order, which is fine, but something from 9 months ago should certainly show up before something from 2012, especially since **without** the boost, the 2014 event was at the top of the list. Right now 2012 is showing up first.

**EDIT 2 (important)**: Ok, so I decided to check what the scores were on my four events, with and without the boost.

2012: 0.37118697    boost: 0.005060354

2013: 0.4639837    boost: 0.005060354

2014: 0.55678046    boost: 0.0044278097

2015: 0.4639837     boost: 0.0044278097

So you can see that the boost is actually making the *newer* onces *worse* than the older ones. Why is it doing this? I don't really understand the equation that the boost is doing, so I don't know why it's making the scores worse.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you just want to order the search based on date, and not use a boost - a boost is meant to trend newer documents higher, not have them in a descending / ascending order.

The example given for boosts will apply a varying boost for documents newer than one year (iirc), while older documents will not receive any boost at all from that clause. Remember that the other search terms will apply boosts as well, and the score for these clauses might be higher / more relevant than the boost applied from the age.

Date boosting is not an exact science, and will have to be applied with boost values according to your other boosts as well (by either changing the values in the recip call, or by prioritising them with ^weight).

Comment: No, I don't. If I search for "Boston Party," I don't want an event called "New York Party" to show up before "Boston Party" on the list just because the New York one is sooner. I want relevancy to the search terms to be considered too. I can't just sort by date. What doesn't make sense to me is that the order it returned was better before I added the boost, so if something in 2014 had the top score initially, adding the boost should certainly leave it with a better score than 2012

Comment: Yes, this is what the boost you've added will do, but as I wrote, you'll have to give it a higher boost to make it more significant compared to the other weights in your search query. If you see [the documentation for recip](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FunctionQuery#recip), you can see that you can either adjust the a parameter to give it a larger base boost (or apply boosts in other ways). You can also adjust the other parameters to get the boost falloff curve to better match what you want.

Comment: I added an edit to my original post, but I checked the scores and the boost is actually making the scores lower for the more recent onces than for the older ones, even though their original scores were better. I don't think changing the boost level is the issue.

Comment: Obviously the boost is the issue - since you're getting lower boosts for newer documents. Make the boost work correctly and it should behave as you want. What is the type of the date field? Seeing the same boost for both 2012/13 and 2014/15 seems weird. Also, be aware of the issue with dates in the future (as noted on the function page on the wiki for date boosting).

Comment: Future dates shouldn't be an issue since I included abs() in the function. My dates are formatted as 2014-04-04T00:00:00Z